# Linux Screen Flickring Problem

Tags: 20.04, screen, hp

While i was working on windows, there was no problem. However screen flickring problem is occuring after i install Ubuntu. I tried the other distos (centos, xubuntu etc), I have still the same problem.

You can see the flickring video [via this link](https://youtu.be/JUnOr6bsA8I)

Computer model: HP Pro 3420 Core i3 2120 3.3GHz

And i have also added some outputs about my machine;

Ubuntu version info:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Graphic Card Model:

```
 lspci -nnk | egrep "VGA|3D|Display" -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0102] (rev 09)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [103c:2ac5]
```

The other informations about gpu:

```
glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 2000 (SNB GT1)
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, 
    GL_INTEL_blackhole_render, GL_INTEL_performance_query, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, 
    GL_INTEL_blackhole_render, GL_INTEL_performance_query, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fog_distance, 
    GL_INTEL_blackhole_render, GL_INTEL_performance_query, 
    GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
```

Resolutions:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 440mm x 250mm
   1600x900      58.03*+
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      61.53    59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Xorg and OpenGl:

```
inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics 
  driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: i915 resolution: 1600x900~58Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 2000 (SNB GT1) 
  v: 3.3 Mesa 20.2.6
```

Comment: If you are having this issue with many different Linux OS it does not appear to be a Ubuntu problem but with the graphics hardware.

Comment: So there is no way to operate any linux distro on this machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have partially solved this issue by launching ubuntu in safe mode. However it keeps the problem for normal starting.